# Return NXDOMAIN for local zone in unbound resolver

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a local recursive resolver based on unbound.

I would like to perform reverse nxdomain-highjacking.
I have defined an exisiting domain I would like to block as a local zone.
Currently, I reply with a local IP for those zones. But I would like to reply with NXDOMAIN.

How can I achieve that in unbound? There is no hint on this in the documentation.

Cheers,
BliZZarD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by defining a static zone with no data in it, since for each non-existing domain a NXDOMAIN is returned.

```
local-zone: "testdomain.test" static
```

The mailing list helped.